# C# Entity Framework Core One Way Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following two classes:

```
    public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public int? CoverPhotoId { get; set; }

        public Photo Cover { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

And

```
    public class Photo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

An album can (or not) have a cover (photo), the CoverPhotoId column stores the id of the photo.

I'm trying to fill the Cover variable, which should be really simple (atleast with SQL).

However with Entity Framework (using modelbuilder (`OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)`) I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your models like:

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Photo Cover { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Photo
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

one `Album` : one `Photo`
this will be done by making a relation between their keys

and in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
    .HasKey(p => p.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
    .HasOne<Photo>(a => a.Cover)
    .WithOne(p => p.Album)
    .HasForeignKey<Photo>(p => p.AlbumId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>()
    .HasKey(p => p.AlbumId);
```

[resource](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-one-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public int? CoverPhotoId { get; set; }

        public virtual Photo CoverPhoto { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

I changed the name of the `Cover` to `CoverPhoto` because (I could be wrong on this, but I think) when you use a virtual object, Entity Framework will actually create an `int` variable in the database that is the variable name with `Id` appended to it, so if your photo is called `CoverPhoto` then the variable in the database will be called `CoverPhotoId`, which you already have so it wouldn't need to create another called `CoverId`. Now Entity Framework should know that you have a reference to a different table, as long as you have a `DbSet` for both `Albums` and `CoverPhotos` in your `DBContext` and you can tell it to include that when the `Album` is queried. You can do this using [Lazy](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx) or [Eager](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx) loading or you can tell it to include it in your query directly:

```
var albums = DBContext.Albums.Include(a => a.CoverPhoto).ToList();
```

I think that in this case if your `Album` doesn't have a `CoverPhoto` then the result would just be an `Album` reference with a null `CoverPhoto` but I don't think that it would crash, you would just need to make sure that you check if its null before accessing it.

You can even use the `DBModelBuilder` to define the `CoverPhoto` as required or optional, which it sounds like in your case you would want optional. But this [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) explains that in better detail.